# Openfire update to latest version Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openfire

I have installed openfire in ubuntu 14.04.

At that time latest version of openfire was : 4.0.1

But now 4.0.2 is available and I want to update to latest version. and I have researched about the same that how can I upgrade openfire to latest version. But I didnt get any solution.

I must have to download latest version from http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp and have to install it.

> **Update information**
>
> Server version 4.0.2 is now available. [Click](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) here to download or read the [change log](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/changelog.html) for more information.

So is there any alternate solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You can install new version doing the following:

```
wget -O openfire.deb http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_4.0.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install openfire.deb
```

If you want to install a diferent version, you only have to change the version in wget command.